# How to assign angularjs value to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angularjs

I am printing a value in a view by `{{ myvalue }}`.

I am assigning that value from the controller as

`$scope.myvalue = "123";`

I want to send this value `myvalue` to ajax call.. So i want to assign this angularjs value to jquery value.

How can i assign this angularjs value to the jquery value ?

I tried like this

```
<script>
    var newvalue = {{myvalue}};
</script>
```

But i am getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` How can i do this ?

Comment: No need to use string interpolation, remove `{{ }}`

Comment: Why not use angular to make the ajax call?

Comment: @Satpal U mean console.log(myvalue); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the scope of element .

```
<script>
var scope = angular.element($("body")).scope();

 var newvalue = scope.myvalue
</script>
```

**Example--**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
     <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script>  
   function test(){
       var scope = angular.element($("body")).scope();
     var newvalue = scope.name;
    alert(newvalue);

   }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

  </body>

</html>
```

**.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  test()
});
```

[Here is the plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/y30wumrFNGzd3F3mRY92?p=preview)

Comment: I am getting undefined

Comment: just take that element which have parent as same controller in which value is defined

Comment: i want full html code where you assigned ng-controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84156/discussion-between-nglover-and-angularangularangular).